# What is "loadall.so"?

Tags: lua, luajit

Looking at the default Lua cpath with luajit:

`luajit -e "print(package.cpath)"`

I get:

`./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so`

What is the purpose of the `loadall.so`? It doesn't actually exist anywhere on my Linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cpath shows you where Lua will look for modules when you "require" a module.  It will try the semicolon separated places, replacing "?" with the name of the module being required. loadall.so is a catch-all place, kind of a last resort.  If it is present (NB: there is no need for it to present), then Lua will load it and look if it finds the module code in it.